# g++ cannot find shared library

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, linker, g++

I apologize that this is redundant, but none of the answers available seem to be able to solve my problem.  I am attempting to compile an executable using a shared object library.  The shared object library is called `libsession.so` and is found in the same directory that I am compiling the executable.  To compile and link, I use the following command

`g++ test_main.cpp -o program -std=c++11 -I ../src/base -L. -lsession`

Unforutanely, I get the *cannot find -lsession* error when linking.  If I change the command to directly reference the shared library as follows

`g++ test_main.cpp -o program -std=c++11 -I ../src/base libsession.so`

then the executable compiles/links and all is well.  Does anyone have any thoughts as to what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The only difference between using an '-l' option and specifying a file
>   name is that '-l' surrounds library with 'lib' and `.a' and searches
>   several directories.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0/gcc_3.html#SEC16

Comment: Also, a good practice in these situations is to use the `-v` flag (verbose) in order to see what the search paths are (amogst other useful informations).

Comment: Awesome!  So, it looks like this will not work for dynamically linked libraries (shared objects).  And that was the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it follows specific naming convention like library name should be preceded by lib. so if you change library name to libsession.so it will work.